# Where do I put the if statement?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, group-by

I wrote this to create a summary of invoices for the past 30 days.  While checking the invoices I notice I pulled a lot of nulls because most of the customers are tax exempt.  I would like to put a IF statement (IF t.TAXABL_23 = 'N' then something to make the tax = 1... it gets kinda gray here)
Where in this mess would the if statement go, or better yet is using an IF statement the logical way to do this.
Thanks.

```
Select  c.ordnum_31 as "Sales Order Number",
    c.invce_31  as "Invoice Number",    
    c.custpo_31 as "Job Name",
    c.ordid_31  as "Other Job Name", 
    c.invdte_31 as "Invoice Date",
    cast (sum((1-(m.DSCRTE_23/100)) * (o.price_32 * o.shpqty_32)) as decimal    (8,2)) as "Net Amount",
    cast (c.frtamt_31 as decimal(8,2)) as Freight,
    cast( ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31)  as decimal (8,2)) as Tax,
    cast (c.MSCAMT_31 as decimal(8,2)) as MISC,
    cast( round (sum((1-(m.DSCRTE_23/100)) * (o.price_32 * o.shpqty_32)) + c.frtamt_31 + c.MSCAMT_31 + ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31),1 ) as decimal(8,2) ) as "Invoice Total" 

from Invoice_Master c
   left join Invoice_Detail o on c.ORDNUM_31 = o.ORDNUM_32
   left join Customer_Master m on c.CUSTID_31 = m.CUSTID_23
   left join Tax_master t on m.TXCDE1_23 = t.TAXCDE_25

where c.invdte_31 >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())

group by
   c.ORDNUM_31,
   c.CUSTID_31,
   c.INVCE_31,
   c.CUSTPO_31,
   c.ORDID_31,
   c.INVDTE_31,
   c.frtamt_31,
   c.taxtot_31,
   m.dscrte_23,
   c.MSCAMT_31,
   t.taxrte_25

order by "Invoice Number"
```

Comment: Are they actually `NULL`'s or are they `'N'`'s?

Comment: Can you include some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @bjones, They are NULL's if the taxable flag is N.

Comment: Maybe a little more detail will prove useful. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for... If I were to guess at it I would say add `ISNULL()` around the entire column. e.g. `ISNULL(cast( ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31)  as decimal (8,2)), 1) Tax,`

Comment: What I would like to do is if the t.TAXABL_23 = 'N' then bypass the tax computation part.  Otherwise perform the tax computation as normal.

Comment: I think that was clear as mud let me try that again.... the tax computation is actually done twice.  1. to get the percentage (t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31 as tax. 2. adds the tax to the taxable amount to get the total..sum((1-(m.DSCRTE_23/100)) * (o.price_32 * o.shpqty_32)) + c.frtamt_31 + c.MSCAMT_31 + ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31),1 ) as decimal(8,2) ) as "Invoice Total".  In both cases when it hits a null the entire formula becomes null'd.  I like the CASE where it would just put a 0 in tax and a 0 where it adds the tax to the taxable amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for a CASE expression:

```
...
... as Freight,
CASE WHEN t.TAXABL_23 = 'N'
     THEN 0                  -- exempt from taxes
     ELSE ...calculate tax...
END as Tax,
... as MISC,
...
```

Otherwise, if you just want to convert NULLs to some value, you can use an ISNULL expression:

```
...
ISNULL(...calculate tax..., 0) AS tax   -- yields 0 when the result of the expression is NULL
...
```

Comment: CASE WHEN t.TAXABL_23 = 'N'
            then  cast( round (sum((1-(m.DSCRTE_23/100)) * (o.price_32 * o.shpqty_32)) + c.frtamt_31 + c.MSCAMT_31 ,1 ) as decimal(8,2) ) as "Invoice Total" 
     ELSE 
   cast( ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31)  as decimal (8,2)) as Tax,
  cast( round (sum((1-(m.DSCRTE_23/100)) * (o.price_32 * o.shpqty_32)) + c.frtamt_31 + c.MSCAMT_31 + ((t.TAXRTE_25 * .01) * c.TAXTOT_31),1 ) as decimal(8,2) ) as "Invoice Total" ,
  end 

from Invoice_Master c

but the syntax is off... could you expand on your answer?  Thanks

Comment: well that comment looks like crap and I can't find how to delete it... sorry

Comment: @Onyxtacular: The "AS ..." must be outside the case clause, ie, after the `END`.

Comment: That did it perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[COALESCE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)** to convert `NULLS`

```
 SELECT COALESCE(fieldWithNull, 'N');
```

Comment: Why use `COALESCE` when there's only a single value?

Comment: OP say is getting lot of null and instead of `NULL` want `'N'`.

Comment: Yes, but why would you prefer `COALESCE` over `ISNULL` in this particular case? `ISNULL` would seem like the logical choice to me.

Comment: @Jens For my understanding `COALESCE` is the ansi standard,

Comment: Check out this article on the differences. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull